# GUI Issues Ubuntu 11.10 GnomeShell

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gui

I am facing a slightly weird issue. GUI's of eclipse, emacs or vim do not work on my comp. Please see the processor usage at the top in http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~namitk/eclipse.png, http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/emacs.png (Also see vim.png at the same url). When I run these programs, the processor usage shoots up but the program GUI fails to load completely (for e.g in emacs/vim - the cursor never appears). I have tried waiting for 10-15 mins just in the hope - but nothing loads. I think its a GUI issue because the non-gui versions (emacs -nw and vi/vim) work normally without any issues. Has anyone faced such an issue previously? Could someone please suggest a way of debugging this issue?

My configuration is (output of uname -a) 
Linux namit-ThinkPad-T61 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux.

Please let me know if any other info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Was due to a very trivial reason. I clicked on the Maximize button of my browser and observed that it hung up (stopped responding) and the processor usage shot up. Also the terminal from which I had started my browser showed a handful of "Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_get_origin: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed" errors. I remember reading that this is a theme issue. I started emacs and maximized its window and it too worked flawlessly. Same with almost all applications - they hang up on reduced window size but work fine in maximized form. Also changing the theme (Any except radiance / ambiance) fixes this issue and I could use applications in maximized or reduced size.

On a side note, is the theme issue persistent or has been fixed?

Comment: Well done for finding an answer - however, remember, since this is a Q&A site, try not end an answer with another question.  Feel free to ask another question if it hasnt already been asked.